# access associated record in view (show page)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have the following association setup:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

  attr_accessible :photo
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small_blog => "250x250#", :large_blog => "680x224#", :thumb => "95x95#" }
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: :imageable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
  attr_accessible :comments, :title, :images_attributes
end
```

To access an image for a post within my index page, for example, I would put my code in a block and loop through using `each`:

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %> 
  <% p.images.each do |i| %>
    <%= image_tag(i.photo.url(:large_blog), :class => 'image') %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So when it comes to accessing that post in my show view where I am only accessing the one record I thought I could access an image like so:

```
<%= image_tag(@post.image.photo.url(:large_blog), :class => 'image') %>
```

But it seems as if I can't as I get an error like: undefined method 'image'.

Im not thinking about something really basic here and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got `has_many` relation with `Image` in your `Post` model, so you can't access `Post.image` as you've got only a collection of images for each Post. In plain English:

You've got here:

A collection of `Post` (`@posts`) which you iterate with `each` method

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
```

Now `p` means single post which has a collection of `images`

```
  <% p.images.each do |i| %>
```

And again, you iterate over `images` and finally display every single `image` attached to `Post`

```
    <%= image_tag(i.photo.url(:large_blog), :class => 'image') %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So as you can see every `Post` may have several images and even if it will have only one image it will be still an Array, so you can access it only by `@post.images.each` or even `@post.images.first` (or `last`) if you want only first one.

If you really want to be able to do also `@post.image` you should add also to Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :image, conditions: { primary: true} # if you want to specify main photo and of course only if you have  'primary' in Image model
(...)
```

You can also add additional conditions (as in code above) to select only newest photo, etc. You can read more about it [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so just in case anyone else is in a similar situation this is what i done to get it to work, unless anyone has a better alternative

```
<% for image in @post.images %>
  <a title=""><%= image_tag(image.photo.url(:large_blog), :class => 'image') %></a>
<% end %>
```